# How to grab an custom element on a web page by JavaScript so that I can simulate user action like click and enter value by coding?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I want to simulate the actions of the user on a web browser by coding, I can do it by `document.getElementbyId or byclassName or by TagName` and then call the method of click or value but how to do it when any website has custom elements that do not have click or value attributes??

Comment: This question is too hard to understand. Clarify and help us help you.

Comment: Just because there is no inline HTML for an event, doesn't mean there is no event handler.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you provide your code and elaborate on what you are looking for.

Comment: Using jQuery, you can call stuff like: `$('.some-button').trigger('click')` to simulate clicking a button.

Comment: @gugateider I want to write a script so I can simulate user action, as you click on a link and it opens and I can easily do by grabbing that link and hot .click() method in script but what if I have a custom tag, like the tag that is created by ReactJs or moreover called component so how can I apply these action on so-called those tag or component?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is unclear. An example would help a lot. *"how to do it when any website has custom elements that do not have click or value attributes"* All `HTMLElement` instances and their subclasses (and custom elements are) have a `click` function. `value` isn't a function, and doesn't seem to relate to the question (you don't "call" `value`, you get or set it on elements that have it, and doing so on elements that don't doesn't make any sense).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to create your custom or customize existing click event and bind it to some elements. You can do that with jquery library.